# Open new page in JQuery bPopup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bpopup

I am using bPopup to open a page in popup container. Now, there is a link in the popup page, i want to open the new page in the already opened bPopup container. Assigning a new page link in anchor tag opens the new page in parent window. I have also used following approach in popup page:

```
$('.icoNext').bind('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$('.popup').bPopup({
    contentContainer:'.popup_content',
    modalClose: false,
    closeClass: 'closeFx',
    loadUrl:'device_new_assignTag.htm'
});
```

});

where the $('.icoNext') is the link in popup page and $(.popup) is in parent page.

Comment: i think, it should be like  $('.popup_content').bPopup({...});

Comment: changing it to $('.popup_content').bPopup({...}); opens the new but the previous popup is still open

Comment: How can i remove the old page from the popup and load a new page in same popup without closing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use the onclose function that is given on the website.

It does close the popup, but in the callback you can open a new popup.

```
  $('element_to_pop_up').bPopup({
        onOpen: function() { alert('onOpen fired'); }, 
        onClose: function() { alert('onClose fired'); }
    }, 
    function() {
        alert('Callback fired');
    });
```

http://dinbror.dk/bpopup/